# IPsec & cypharing algorithm Linux Ubuntu

Tags: ipsec

What is the package that contain the implementation of IPsec and what is the package that contain the implementation of cypher algorithms that IPsec uses for enctiption?

Comment: answer updated!

Answer (score 0):

IPsec package you can install with ipsec-tools package. To install that open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then type as

```
sudo apt-get install ipsec-tools
```

and cypher algorithms are not direct but you can get them through the python .

```
sudo apt-get install python-otr
```

you can get any package source with this command

```
 sudo apt-get source <packagename>
```

**for example:**

```
 sudo apt-get source ipsec-tools
```

Comment: I need the source code for both IPsec and cypher algorithms

Comment: can you help @Jai

Comment: @AhmadDarwish I already gave you the proper commands to get the source code , what else you need ?